# HTML5 replacement input required tag for older browsers

Tags: html, forms, input, internet-explorer-9, required

I have already implemented the required tag into a selection of forms and input fields throughout a site. I was wondering if their was a script that would automatically perform the HTLM5 required tag functions on older browsers (e.g. IE9). This is so I don't have to edit either the form or input tags and hopefully just include script/css files in a header.

Thanks for any help

Comment: This question doesn't show any research. We would need to see your code to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is some form validation script/plugin.  While all of those validators offer the `required` functionality, almost all of them offer more additional validation tasks too.

If you use jQuery, there is the [validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) plugin

If you don't use jQuery, take a look at this [list of HTML5 polyfills](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#web-forms)

Comment: Hi, I was aware of the main alternatives but all these require you to use the id or class attributes. I was hoping to find one that provided a fallback for the required attribute without having to use class or id